Error 415 "Unsupported Media Type" when testing an endpoint with Spring Boot
Description:
I am developing a web service using Spring Boot, and I am encountering an issue when testing an endpoint that should receive a list of DTOs and a file. When I perform the test, I get the following error:
Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported.
"status": 415,
"error": "Unsupported Media Type"


I have annotated my controller method with @RequestPart to receive the list of DTOs and have configured Postman to send the data as form-data, but I still get the error.
Here is my controller method:
@PostMapping("/upload")
    public  ResponseEntity<?> handleFileUpload(
                                @RequestPart(required = false) List<AtributoDto> atributoDtoList,
                                @RequestPart( value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file,
                         HttpSession session,
                        @RequestPart(value = "entityId", required = false) Long entityId) {
        log.info("Inicio de handleFileUpload con file: {}", file);
        ResponseEntity<?> response;
        try {
            response = ResponseEntity.ok((atributoService.processAtributos(atributoDtoList,file,session,entityId)));
            log.info("El proceso de carga de archivos se completó con éxito");
        }catch (IOException e){
            log.error("Error en el proceso de carga de archivos: {}", e.getMessage());
            response = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error en el proceso de carga de archivos");
        }
        return response;
    }

service method
@Transactional
    public String processAtributos(List<AtributoDto> atributoDtoList, MultipartFile file, HttpSession session, Long entityId) throws IOException {
        log.info("Inicio del método processAtributos");
        List<Atributo> ats = new ArrayList<>();
        try {

            if (atributoDtoList != null) {
                log.info("Procesando lista de atributos y archivo");

                StringBuilder listaAtributos = new StringBuilder(" ");
                String consultaid = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < atributoDtoList.size(); i++) {
                    AtributoDto dto = atributoDtoList.get(i);
                    Atributo atributo = new Atributo();
                    atributo.setNombreAtributo(dto.nombreAtributo());
                    atributo.setDescripcion(dto.descripcion());
                    atributo.setXxcntIdTipoDatoFk(dto.xxcntIdTipoDatoFk());
                    atributo.setLongitud(dto.longitud());
                    atributo.setEsAuditable(dto.esAuditable());
                    atributo.setMascara(dto.mascara());
                    atributo.setDueno(dto.dueno());
                    atributo.setProcesoNace(dto.procesoNace());
                    atributo.setEsRequeridoEnFuente(dto.esRequeridoEnFuente());
                    atributo.setXxcntIdConsultaFk(dto.xxcntIdConsultaFk());
                    atributo.setNombreConsulta(dto.nombreConsulta());
                    atributo.setIncluirModificar(dto.modificadoPor());
                    if (i == 0) {
                        atributo.setEsLlavePrimaria('1');
                        listaAtributos = new StringBuilder("'" + atributo.getNombreConsulta() + "'");
                        consultaid = String.valueOf(atributo.getXxcntIdConsultaFk());
                    } else {
                        atributo.setEsLlavePrimaria('0');
                        listaAtributos.append(",'").append(atributo.getNombreConsulta()).append("'");
                    }
                    atributo.setEstatus('1');

                    /**
                     * Si el objeto JSON tiene una propiedad "found" que es igual a "1", el código interpreta esto como una señal de que el atributo ya existe y necesita ser modificado.
                     * En este caso, busca el atributo existente en la base de datos usando su ID, actualiza sus propiedades, y luego guarda los cambios en la base de datos.
                     * */
                    if ("1".equals(dto.found())) { // si el atributo ya existe
                        atributo.setUsuarioModificacion("UsuarioCNT");
                        Long idmodificar = dto.xxcntIdAtributoPk();
                        atributo.setXxcntIdAtributoPk(idmodificar);
                        Date date = new Date();
                        atributo.setFechaModificacion(date);
                        Atributo atrimodificar = getAtributoById(idmodificar);
                        atributo.setFechaCreacion(atrimodificar.getFechaCreacion());
                        atributo.setUsuarioCreacion(atrimodificar.getUsuarioCreacion());
                    } else {
                        atributo.setUsuarioCreacion("UsuarioCNT");
                        Date date = new Date();
                        atributo.setFechaCreacion(date);
                    }
                    Atributo at = createNewAtributte(atributo);
                    ats.add(at);
                }
                updateDeleteAtributos(consultaid, listaAtributos.toString());
                consultaDominioService.activarConsulta(consultaid);
                log.info("Lista de atributos procesada");
            } else {
                log.info("No se recibió lista de atributos");
            }


            if (file != null) {
                log.info("Archivo recibido, iniciando procesamiento");
                FileContentHolderDTO fileContentHolderDTO = getFileContentHolderDTO(file);
                List<String> fRow = fileContentHolderDTO.getFRow();
                // escribir el archivo en el disco
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                Path path = Paths.get(fileContentHolderDTO.getDestination() + file.getOriginalFilename()); // concatena el nombre del archivo con la ruta
                Files.write(path, bytes);

                Entidad e = entidadService.findById(entityId); // obtiene la entidad por ID desde el front es xxcntIdEntidadPk de la clase Entidad
                List<EntidadAtributoPadre> eapToPersist = new ArrayList();
                int i = 0;
                var entidadValorPadre = "";
                List<Long> idsConsultas = new ArrayList();
                //idsConsultas.add(((Atributo) ats.get(0)).getXxcntIdConsultaFk());
                idsConsultas.add(ats.get(0).getXxcntIdConsultaFk());
                List<Long> attrIdSet = getIdAttributeByQueryIdSet(idsConsultas);
                List<ValorAtributo> queriesVa = valorAtributoService.findValorAtributoByIdAttSet(attrIdSet);
                Long firstAttOfFirstQueryOfFirstDomain = -1L;
                for (Atributo a : ats) {
                    if (isFirstAttributeOfFirstQueryOfFirstDomain(a.getXxcntIdAtributoPk())) {
                        firstAttOfFirstQueryOfFirstDomain = a.getXxcntIdAtributoPk();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                for (String row : fRow) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        i++;
                    } else {
                        for (int index = 0; index < row.split(":::").length; index++) {
                            Atributo currentAtt = ats.get(index);
                            Object[] existsValnDb = valorAtributoService.existsValueInMemory(row.split(":::")[index], currentAtt.getXxcntIdAtributoPk(), queriesVa);

                            ValorAtributo valnDB = null;

                            String vaInDBAuxS = "";
                            if ((Boolean) existsValnDb[0]) {
                                valnDB = queriesVa.get((Integer) existsValnDb[1]);
                                vaInDBAuxS = valnDB.getValorAtributo() != null ? valnDB.getValorAtributo() : "";
                            }
                            String col = row.split(":::")[index];
                            if (!(Boolean) existsValnDb[0]) {
                                ValorAtributo va = new ValorAtributo();
                                va.setEntidadAtributo(row.split(":::")[0]);
                                va.setFechaCreacion(new Date());
                                va.setFechaModificacion(new Date());
                                va.setUsuarioCreacion("UsuarioCNT");
                                va.setUsuarioModificacion("UsuarioCNT");
                                va.setValorAtributo(col);
                                if (currentAtt.getXxcntIdTipoDatoFk() == 1L) {
                                    try {
                                        va.setValorAtributoNumero(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(col)));
                                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                                        va.setValorAtributoNumero(null);
                                    }
                                } else if (currentAtt.getXxcntIdTipoDatoFk() == 3L) {
                                    try {
                                        va.setValorAtributoFecha(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(col));
                                    } catch (ParseException ex) {
                                        Logger.getLogger(AtributoController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                    } finally {
                                        va.setValorAtributoFecha(null);
                                    }
                                }
                                boolean isFirst = currentAtt.getXxcntIdAtributoPk().longValue() == firstAttOfFirstQueryOfFirstDomain.longValue();
                                if (isFirst) {
                                    long consultaFK = currentAtt.getXxcntIdConsultaFk();
                                    long me = e.getXxcntIdEntidadPk();
                                    Long parent = e.getEntidadPadre();
                                    long fParent = parent == 0L ? me : parent;

                                    entidadAtributoPadreService.cleanByIdParentIdAndEntityValue(me, fParent, col);
                                    boolean hasParent = (e.getEntidadPadre() != null) && (e.getEntidadPadre() != 0L);
                                    int[] parentIndexes = indexesOfParentAndUserValues(consultaFK, hasParent, ats);
                                    EntidadAtributoPadre eap = new EntidadAtributoPadre();
                                    eap.setEntidadId(me);
                                    eap.setEntidadPadreId(fParent);
                                    try {
                                        eap.setValorEntidadPadre(row.split(":::")[parentIndexes[0]]);
                                    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                                        eap.setValorEntidadPadre(col);
                                    }
                                    eap.setValorEntidad(col);
                                    Object pv = null;
                                    try {
                                        pv = row.split(":::")[parentIndexes[1]];
                                    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                                    }
                                    String s = pv != null ? pv.toString() : "";
                                    eap.setValorUsuario(s);
                                    if (eapToPersist == null) {
                                        eapToPersist = new ArrayList(); // se inicializa pero jamas se usa en el metodo
                                    }
                                    entidadValorPadre = eap.getValorEntidadPadre();
                                    entidadAtributoPadreService.addParentEntityAttribute(eap);
                                } else {
                                    entidadValorPadre = entidadAtributoPadreService.findParentValueByEntityValueAndEntityId(va.getEntidadAtributo(), e.getXxcntIdEntidadPk());
                                }
                                va.setXxcntIdAtributoFk(currentAtt.getXxcntIdAtributoPk());
                                va.setEntidadValorPadre(entidadValorPadre);
                                this.valorAtributoService.addValorAtributo(va);
                            } else if (!col.equals(vaInDBAuxS)) {
                                ValorAtributoRespaldo var = getValorAtributoRespaldo(valnDB);
                                valorAtributoRespaldoService.create(var);
                                valnDB.setValorAtributo(col);
                                this.valorAtributoService.update(valnDB);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                log.info("Procesamiento de archivo finalizado");

            } else {
                log.info("No se recibió archivo");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Error al procesar los atributos", e);
            throw new IOException("Error al procesar los atributos" + e.getMessage(),e);
        }
        log.info("Fin del método processAtributos");
        return "exito";
    }

And this is how I configure Postman:
Method: POST
URL: [ENDPOINT_URL]
Body: form-data
Key: listDTO
Value: [JSON_OF_DTO_LIST]
Key: file
Value: [FILE]

I noticed that if I change the @RequestPart annotation to @RequestBody for the list of DTOs and send the data as JSON in Postman, it works correctly for the list, but the issue persists with the file.
Can anyone help me understand why I am receiving this error and how I can fix it?
Thanks in advance!

You should provide the @PostMapping annotation with the correct produces value you expect. Here it seems like application/octet-stream should do the trick. By default it is accepting only application/json input.

@Chasca The error reported is not about producing the response but about consuming the request.

True, the comment is valid though, just add the consumes part instead of produces, my bad

If you send a combination of parameters with a file you should use @RequestParam for the parameters and @RequestPart for the file. Like this:
@PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleFileUpload(
               @RequestParam(required = false) List<AtributoDto> atributoDtoList,
               @RequestPart(required = false) MultipartFile file,
               @RequestParam(required = false) Long entityId,
               HttpSession session) {
//...
}


"Thank you very much. I couldn't test it anymore because we checked that the project doesn't use it. I'm migrating a JEE project to Spring Boot."

If you are wanting to return a file in your request you should update your request mapping to the following:
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", produces = {"application/octet-stream"})

You could also use org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE instead of the string value there if desired.

The error reported is not about producing the response but about consuming the request.

"Thank you very much. I couldn't test it anymore because we checked that the project doesn't use it. I'm migrating a JEE project to Spring Boot."
